# Using 'scanf', what is the difference between having a variable or pointer in the second argument?

Tags: c, scanf

What is the difference between having a variable or pointer in the second argument of `scanf`.

For example:

```
scanf("%f",&r);
```

vs

```
scanf("%f",r);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass a value to any function, that value gets copied prior to the function call. The function uses the copy, and that copy is then discarded when the function returns.

`scanf` needs to put its results somewhere you can get them back after the function has returned. Thus, you don't give it any disposable copies of anything. Instead, you tell where the things live, so that it can store the user's input right there. That's a pointer. In short : you *always* pass a pointer to `scanf`.

However, depending on the value's type, pointers will show with a different notation. That is, if you're scanning for an integer `i`, for instance, of type `int`, you'll have to take `i`'s address (= transform into a pointer) by adding an amperstand in front of it : `scanf("%d",&i);`. Whereas if you're scanning for a string `s`, its type is `char*`, which is *already* a pointer to a buffer of characters (take note of the trailing star in the type). The adress of the buffer is what scanf expects, and therefore there's no need to dereference : `scanf("%s",s);`.

Comment: Almost perfect, save for the exact inversion of what "dereferencing" means.

Comment: Bollocks, you're right. Tired day, bad sentences...I've edited quite a few times to fix typos already, and missed that one. I'll get on it. THANKS.